# My game object move as soon as it gets some input

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn Unity by myself. I'm recreating pong in 3d with Unity objects. I started a few minutes ago and every time I throw any input into the pad its y coordinate shifts to 2.6, I have no idea why. Can someone help?

```
public class PadMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private CharacterController pad;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private Vector3 movement;
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 50.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        pad = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, 0);
        movement = direction * speed;
        pad.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

SOLVED: there was a capsule collider out of place!

Answer (score 1):

Afternoon,  I recently copied your code into a 'Unity3d',  ".cs",  File and actually I created a cube and placed my game into a 2d mode,  After this I named my file "PadMovement",  after that I dragged it onto my newly created cube,  Once I had done that I tried to click play and noticed that my cube didn't have a "CharacterController",  attached to my cube,  Once I had done that and clicked play I was eligible to have my "paddle",  smoothly move around the screen @ 50.0f along the X axis.

Knowingly,   My Input came from the "Character Controller",  My Speed came from the Serial field you had for speed!

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have a `CapsuleCollider` Component or some other collider on the same GameObject that you have this PadMovement Component on? That sounds like a height where it might just be trying to pop the object out of ground collision.

It should be harmless if that's all it is. If you really want an object to be at y of 0 you can attach it to a parent object and have that parent stay at 0.